# What kind of clamps are used to attach a main panel's grounding wire to two grounding rods?

Tags: electrical-panel, grounding

The grounding clamps I've seen online  (see pic) don't seem suited to attaching a main panel's grounding wire to two grounding rods; the orientation of the part of the clamp that grips the wire does not appear designed for rods sunk vertically into the soil and the wire running *parallel to the earth's surface  and in a straight line* between the two rods. Is there another type of clamp used for this purpose, which has the wire-gripping section rotated 90 degrees?

[image: grounding clamp]

Comment: That's a clamp more suited to connecting to a water pipe, though it may also include ground rods in its listing. A ground rod clamp does not need to be multipart, as it slips over the wire and over the end of the rod- so the much simpler ones that are a single loop and bolt are more commonly used.

Comment: @jsotola duly edited. thanks

Answer (score 3):

It's perfectly normal for the wire to be clamped parallel to the rods.

You appear to be under the impression that the wire must run in a perfectly straight line horizontally. This is not true. Typically the wire runs along, goes up (bending), down through the clamp, bends again and runs on to the next rod.

If I trip across the olde fashioned film pictures, mine does that 5 times before terminating at the well casing (I had some extra rods and nothing better to do with them than use them, so I did.)

In my personal experience (limited, but in the several dozen range) this is the most common sort of clamp used on ground rods, where the wire is clamped directly to the rod, parallel to it.

[image: Ground rod clamp]

*[Image source](https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fs3.amazonaws.com%2Fcesco-content%2Funilog%2FBatch6%2F783786%2F479059-ProductImageURL.jpg&f=1&nofb=1&ipt=b88187a669c726fd3f4b8fed878679b63158af9643217515ad5299cb78ceb815&ipo=images) no affiliation*

There may indeed be clamps that allow a straight-line horizontal run, but they are not terribly common in my personal experience, and not required.

Comment: From looking at diagrams on the web, it seemed  the wire between the two rods must run below ground. Is that right? If so, and  the wire runs parallel to the rod before making a turn to the horizontal, a trench about six inches deeper would be necessary. Since the grounding rods would be a retrofit (grounded to water mains now), and the rods would have to go in an area where there is a lot of 75 year-old shrubbery with very thick roots, I was hoping to keep the trench as shallow as possible, just to make that part of the task easier. We're right up against the house with the shrubs in the way.

Comment: I don't know what other constraints you have, but going out into a lawn is typically easier than trying to stay beside a house with shrubbery. Of course you might have the shrubbery bouned by concrete situation, and then you're stuck with fighting the shrubbery.

Comment: Yeah, lots of odd constraints when retrofitting, including roof drains that cut across the lawn at an angle below ground, converge at a "Y", and daylight at the curb.    :-)

Comment: @mrblint The grounding electrode conductor ("GEC") is not generally required to be buried, except to protect it where subject to physical damage. Up against the house seems "not subject to damage" (unless maybe by hedge trimmers?). If you like, you could route the GEC off the house to the first rod, then back to and along the surface of the house, ultimately routing out to the second rod.

Comment: @GregHill Thanks for the helpful info. That will make the task a lot easier.